# Can Flink deal with Key Selector Functions whose returned keys change over time?

Tags: apache-flink

The idea would be to implement a [`KeySelector`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/functions/KeySelector.html) that maps its input objects to a specific partition key,
but this key can change over time.
The mapping rules can be saved in, say, a database,
and the `KeySelector` would update them periodically or on demand.

I'm not sure if this would cause problems for Flink's state or stream-partitioning mechanism.
For example, if an input `Foo` was initially mapped to partition key 0,
but later changes to partition key 1,
and key 0 is not used any longer,
will Flink simply "forget" key 0 at some point?

[Small Kotlin example.](https://gist.github.com/asardaes/65f3dee3d1e3103b4c82d4309d071592)

Answer (score 2):

No, I can't imagine how that could work. Flink depends on the KeySelectors being deterministic. If you change keys like this then any key-partitioned state will be totally confused.

You can, however, arrange for Flink to discard state for stale keys. See [StateTtlConfig](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/stream/state/state.html#state-time-to-live-ttl).

Comment: I have [this small example](https://gist.github.com/asardaes/65f3dee3d1e3103b4c82d4309d071592) that seems to work fine (it's Kotlin). If it's not too much trouble, could you confirm that it is definitely an unforeseen use-case?

Comment: Well, sure, with the parallelism set to one, perhaps nothing will go wrong.